# The initial viewcontroller/windowcontroller/window remains retained after closing window—how do I deinitalize it?

Tags: swift, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I have an macOS app that opens up multiple tabs. When a new tab is opened, it's retained by the app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var tabControllers:[WindowController] = []
}

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.tabControllers.append(self)
        self.window?.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        if let wc = NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateInitialController() as? WindowController,
            let window = wc.window {
            self.window?.addTabbedWindow(window, ordered: .below)
            window.order(.above, relativeTo: self.window.hashValue)
  
        }
    }
    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow,
            let wc = window.windowController as? WindowController,
            let index = tabControllers.firstIndex(of: wc) {
            
            (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.tabControllers.remove(at: index)
            
        }
    }
}
```

For all newly created tabs, this code ensures when the new tab is open, there's a strong reference that keeps it alive. When the user goes to close the tab, it removes the strong reference, which deinitializes the object. Works great except for the initial windowcontroller that the app starts with. If the user adds a new tab and closes the first window/tab, all the above code is called, but the initial window is not deinitialized.

How do I deinitialize that first window/tab?

Comment: How is the initial windowcontroller created?

Comment: @Willeke -- via Main.storyboard.

Comment: Switch off "Initial Controller" and load the first window from code?

Comment: But where is it being retained? Ideally, you could identify where it’s being retained and set it to nil.

Comment: I don't know but it must be retained somewhere, otherwise it would be released and of no use.

Comment: Update:  I’ve discovered that `NSWindow` has a property called [`isReleasedWhenClosed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-isreleasedwhenclosed). However, setting that to true doesn’t seem to do the trick. In fact, it causes the app to crash when closing newly-created tabs.

Comment: Quote: "Release when closed, however, is ignored for windows owned by window controllers."

Comment: It looks like the window controller is retained by `NSApplicationMain`.